# calculate growth rates over columns by iteration in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe

```
#Example for Stackoverflow
df = pd.DataFrame({'Ticker': ['AAPL', 'MSFT', 'IBM'],
                   'totalRevenue_ttm': [386017000000, 192557000000, 50608000000],
                   'revenues_2021': [365817000000, 168088000000, 57351000000],
                   'revenues_2020': [274515000000, 143015000000, 55179000000],
                   'revenues_2019': [260174000000, 125843000000, 57714000000],
                   'revenues_2018': [265595000000, 110360000000, 79591000000]})
```

I would like to calculate the growth rates of sales for 2021, 2020 and 2019.

If I use the following code, I get the growth rate for 2021

```
col=2
df[str(revenues.columns[col]) + "_Growth"]=(df.iloc[:, col]-revenues.iloc[:, col+1])/df.iloc[:, col+1]
df
```

The result looks like:
[image]

How can I iterate over the columns, so I can calculate also revenues_2020_Growth and revenues_2019_Growth

thank your help, I very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pct_change`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pct_change.html) on columns:

```
out = (df.filter(regex='revenues_\d+').sort_index(axis=1, ascending=False)
         .pct_change(-1, axis=1).round(2)
         .iloc[:,1:].add_suffix('_Growth')
       )
```

output:

```
   revenues_2021_Growth  revenues_2020_Growth  revenues_2019_Growth
0                  0.33                  0.06                 -0.02
1                  0.18                  0.14                  0.14
2                  0.04                 -0.04                 -0.27
```

combining with input:

```
out = df.join(df
 .filter(regex='revenues_\d+').sort_index(axis=1, ascending=False)
 .pct_change(-1, axis=1).round(2)
 .iloc[:,:-1].add_suffix('_Growth')
)
```

output:

```
  Ticker  totalRevenue_ttm  revenues_2021  revenues_2020  revenues_2019  revenues_2018  revenues_2021_Growth  revenues_2020_Growth  revenues_2019_Growth
0   AAPL      386017000000   365817000000   274515000000   260174000000   265595000000                  0.33                  0.06                 -0.02
1   MSFT      192557000000   168088000000   143015000000   125843000000   110360000000                  0.18                  0.14                  0.14
2    IBM       50608000000    57351000000    55179000000    57714000000    79591000000                  0.04                 -0.04                 -0.27
```

Comment: Ty, but what if I would like to keep also the other columns?

Comment: `df.join(out)` ;)

Comment: Perfect! :) TYYYY!